# HTML injection in Angular is not loading

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am currently building an Angular web application which displays the map of a user given location. This map is provided by an API, which returns it in HTML, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

  <script>
    L_NO_TOUCH = false;
    L_DISABLE_3D = false;
  </script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Leaflet.awesome-markers/2.0.2/leaflet.awesome-markers.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/python-visualization/folium/master/folium/templates/leaflet.awesome.rotate.css"/>
  <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;}</style>
  <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <style>
    #map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d {
      position: relative;
      width: 100.0%;
      height: 100.0%;
      left: 0.0%;
      top: 0.0%;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="folium-map" id="map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d" ></div>

</body>
<script>

  var map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d = L.map(
    "map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d",
    {
      center: [48.80562052145304, 2.1278466849826074],
      crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
      zoom: 1,
      zoomControl: true,
      preferCanvas: false,
    }
  );





  var tile_layer_4dd23536f2c64dfa9af9e3307729bf11 = L.tileLayer(
    "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    {"attribution": "\u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\"\u003eOpenStreetMap\u003c/a\u003e contributors \u0026copy; \u003ca href=\"http://cartodb.com/attributions\"\u003eCartoDB\u003c/a\u003e, CartoDB \u003ca href =\"http://cartodb.com/attributions\"\u003eattributions\u003c/a\u003e", "detectRetina": false, "maxNativeZoom": 18, "maxZoom": 18, "minZoom": 0, "noWrap": false, "opacity": 1, "subdomains": "abc", "tms": false}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_f41f8f735c3c474abdb408604e4470c5 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8129345, 2.1295637], [48.8129411, 2.1295093], [48.813039, 2.1287001], [48.8131322, 2.1279296], [48.8131352, 2.1279165], [48.81315, 2.1278513], [48.8131858, 2.1276999]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_6f6ce7e53b294bddb4e79330b765aae8 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8131858, 2.1276999], [48.8121848, 2.1270939]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_0f34e9e2d4a149cd94f68dd97270963d = L.polyline(
    [[48.8121848, 2.1270939], [48.8117637, 2.1268224], [48.8116938, 2.1267804]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_d966b82da1724591935df855a730c0d6 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8116938, 2.1267804], [48.8116297, 2.1267507], [48.8115303, 2.1267021], [48.8113857, 2.1266141], [48.8106977, 2.1261952]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_1918c8a205604c2f86f83e699b9e792f = L.polyline(
    [[48.8106977, 2.1261952], [48.8099203, 2.1257292]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_86a6b0d068f846dd979dcc4bbe7c95d3 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8099203, 2.1257292], [48.8098549, 2.1256399], [48.8097649, 2.1255683], [48.8096529, 2.1254511]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_2ce2100085324240acbd0b1bf79898e3 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8096529, 2.1254511], [48.8096152, 2.1254052], [48.8095617, 2.125379]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_da0bfe9721154534bc6aeceaa6599300 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8095617, 2.125379], [48.8094787, 2.1253619]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_ab02762697e04a93a96a65864670ed44 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8094787, 2.1253619], [48.8094102, 2.1253455]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_87a3a7a6f2db44a7a601fac248921745 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8094102, 2.1253455], [48.8093472, 2.1253137], [48.809274, 2.1252908], [48.8090941, 2.1252255]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_d3a9c43fc7714866a1d1aa00c20db7cb = L.polyline(
    [[48.8090941, 2.1252255], [48.8090871, 2.1252215], [48.8086838, 2.1249868], [48.8086529, 2.1249674], [48.8086271, 2.1249549], [48.8085465, 2.1249066], [48.808528, 2.1248955]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_f4749b87c0dd4424b2be996e82c1a1ee = L.polyline(
    [[48.808528, 2.1248955], [48.8084326, 2.1248411], [48.8084082, 2.1248245], [48.8082998, 2.1247563], [48.8078556, 2.1244726], [48.8075109, 2.1242561]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_1bcc2fb7b3be4da3b748eefdefe64ceb = L.polyline(
    [[48.8075109, 2.1242561], [48.8074658, 2.1241674], [48.8070804, 2.1239416], [48.8067274, 2.1237369], [48.8066376, 2.1237464]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_0beaab9ba1ba4f50bf5f95c8a872d091 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8066376, 2.1237464], [48.8060512, 2.1233703], [48.8057453, 2.1231939], [48.8056622, 2.1231491], [48.8051683, 2.1228438], [48.8051378, 2.122825], [48.8050828, 2.1228102], [48.8050475, 2.1228182], [48.8050139, 2.1228397], [48.8049813, 2.1228955], [48.8047558, 2.1237495]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_160e471cd5744076803d4714fc516e7e = L.polyline(
    [[48.8047558, 2.1237495], [48.8047107, 2.1239558]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_2c3f7541f0964c2ab93a20751463a6da = L.polyline(
    [[48.8047107, 2.1239558], [48.8046429, 2.1240064], [48.8045993, 2.1240428], [48.8045608, 2.1240748], [48.8045087, 2.1241312], [48.8044716, 2.1242023], [48.8044521, 2.1242733], [48.804444, 2.1243471]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_b7178c9334a14d4d920db374da09d39f = L.polyline(
    [[48.804444, 2.1243471], [48.8044751, 2.1244061], [48.8044852, 2.1245459], [48.804543, 2.1253075], [48.8046129, 2.1263118]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_08092e2c4acc4bd6bf23b07d21bc0bc3 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8046129, 2.1263118], [48.8045811, 2.1263628], [48.804569, 2.1264607], [48.8045463, 2.1265493], [48.8045242, 2.1266085], [48.8044345, 2.1267289], [48.8043338, 2.1268187]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_beb245888d84480ca8058e38071dd715 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8043338, 2.1268187], [48.8042048, 2.1268402], [48.8040689, 2.1268468], [48.8039419, 2.1268357], [48.8038573, 2.1268064], [48.8037508, 2.1267517], [48.8034129, 2.1265653], [48.8033767, 2.1265444], [48.8033204, 2.126503], [48.8032461, 2.1264527]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_a2c33ded71c14a0193380ddcd6038186 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8032461, 2.1264527], [48.8031166, 2.1263714]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_b6364f57029840b48bfc9d168bb21ac6 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8031166, 2.1263714], [48.8030529, 2.1266028], [48.8030426, 2.1266477], [48.8029778, 2.1270681], [48.8028136, 2.1276588], [48.8027602, 2.1278693]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_b366e2e170d143d39a85698f6cda47e8 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8027602, 2.1278693], [48.8024832, 2.1289162], [48.8024399, 2.1290383], [48.8023564, 2.129221], [48.8022766, 2.1295177], [48.8022446, 2.1296351]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_0478c88d96ec4e5b8b29c31c1cfc172c = L.polyline(
    [[48.8022446, 2.1296351], [48.8022131, 2.1297433]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_8b3f8204d4b848c19c6e3a7fd0725c5f = L.polyline(
    [[48.8022131, 2.1297433], [48.8021092, 2.1301312], [48.8020893, 2.1302058], [48.8020672, 2.1302884], [48.801972, 2.1306437], [48.8019267, 2.1308129]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_899387d1acfb455daa753cbf1077db79 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8019267, 2.1308129], [48.8018092, 2.131252], [48.8018001, 2.1312857], [48.8017328, 2.1315453]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_8277d9d114bf4db4861771d3ff8a432b = L.polyline(
    [[48.8017328, 2.1315453], [48.8016671, 2.1318049]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_19321c96fa57403bbab8a0e6f802afa0 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8016671, 2.1318049], [48.8013584, 2.1329971]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_03f2aa582db14ca4bb3c68b98c3a7ae9 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8013584, 2.1329971], [48.8011973, 2.1335915]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_26c1aabf929e479483ad634ca6e1c2d7 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8011973, 2.1335915], [48.8011213, 2.1338854], [48.8010798, 2.1340459], [48.8010346, 2.1342175]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_b4c777d6cc28420dbb006e99ae091d85 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8010346, 2.1342175], [48.8009455, 2.1345401], [48.8008055, 2.13508], [48.8005611, 2.1360227], [48.8005059, 2.1362259]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  var poly_line_1b9433d172d2427fa31fa1d96c0f6872 = L.polyline(
    [[48.8005059, 2.1362259], [48.8004427, 2.136187], [48.800291, 2.1360937], [48.8002063, 2.1360446]],
    {"bubblingMouseEvents": true, "color": "#cc0000", "dashArray": null, "dashOffset": null, "fill": false, "fillColor": "#cc0000", "fillOpacity": 0.2, "fillRule": "evenodd", "lineCap": "round", "lineJoin": "round", "noClip": false, "opacity": 1, "smoothFactor": 1.0, "stroke": true, "weight": 5}
  ).addTo(map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d);


  map_25a91690496d48249c98a7e3d433fa9d.fitBounds(
    [[48.8002063, 2.1228102], [48.8131858, 2.1362259]],
    {}
  );

</script>
```

Note that when I open this HTML in a standalone .html file, it works perfectly.

I had three ideas:

- Display HTML in a div
- Display HTML in an iframe
- Save the HTML in a file and include this file in the iframe

### **Display HTML in a div**

With this code :

```
<div id="map" class="map" [ngClass]="{'map-active': foundPath}" [innerHTML]="html">

</div>
```

The HTML is properly loaded, every div is in place, but nothing is displayed. I guess this comes from the various scripts no being executed with this method.

I tried loading the scripts after loading the DOM content, but I get various errors from the script.

### **Display HTML in an iframe**

With the code:

```
<iframe id="map" class="map" [ngClass]="{'map-active': foundPath}" [src]="html">

</iframe>
```

The content is not loaded because it does not expect HTML.

### **Save the HTML in a file and include this file in the iframe**

It appears that I can't create a file in the assets folder from Angular to do that.

Do you have any idea how I could do that?

Comment: have you tried this  **var elem = document.getElementById("map") as HTMLSelectElement** elem.innerHTML = html; on **AfterViewInit**  ?

Comment: you can see detail about AfterViewInit in the link https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil thanks for your comment. I tried this :

`ngAfterViewInit() {
    const elem = document.getElementById('map') as HTMLSelectElement;
    elem.innerHTML = this.path.html;
  }`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Any warnings in the console?

Maybe angular blocks ur HTML because of XSS. You can read more about this and how to solve it, at the Angular Docs: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: No warning so far. I add issues with XSS and DomSanitizer, but even after disabling this I just get nothing.